# How to implement plugin architecture in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an interface in my main library. There will be multiple different implementations of this interface, those implementation will be part of different libraries, possibly distributed as nuget packages.

As per the requirement, user should be able to use a particular implementation by adding its corresponding nuget.

Providing an analogy, lets suppose I have an interface, *IPizzaProvider*.

```
public interface IPizzaProvider
{
   Pizza GetMePizza(customizationParameter);
}
```

There will be multiple different implementations of this distributed in different NuGet packages.

1. DominosPizzaProvider
2. PizzaHutPizzaProvider
3. XYZPizzaProvider blah blah

Thus, these are different plugins for my main library.

Use Case:

1. A user adds my main library in their application.
2. Next, users as per their choice adds a particular nuget package (plugin) in their application.
3. User provides customization parameters to my main library.
4. Now, my library should be able to get object of *Pizza* through the interface without worrying about the implementation.

This will not only will help me to have loose coupling/ abstract implementation  through an interface but also facilitate separate release cadence for supporting additional providers in future. I don't have to release my existing main library.

Additionally, users can also implement my interface themselves and use it with my main library.

Problem statement: How to load those DLLs in my main library and instantiate the implementation class dynamically at runtime.

One possible solution is to ***.NET Reflection***. But then I have to scan all individual DLLs and find the assembly which contains implementation.

```
List<Assembly> allAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);    

foreach (string dll in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
    allAssemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFile(dll));

List<Type> providers = allAssemblies
    .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
    .Where(t => IPizzaProvider.IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.IsClass).ToList();
```

There might be hundreds of DLLs at runtime path of the application and scanning them all might cause performance hit.

Is there any other possible way to implement this plugin architecture in .NET?
Java uses SPI for similar problem statement and has ServiceLoader class to load different implementation. It involves META-INF folder etc.

Comment: Why not just use [.NET's dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection)?

Comment: Have you benchmarked this? Even with "hundreds of DLLs" this doesn't take long. Otherwise, it sounds like you want to use a config file or similar to load a specific DLL, so is that your question?

Comment: I would second the suggestion to use dependency injection. That should let the user run multiple instances of the library, with different sets of "plugins". Also note that "plugin" may be interpreted as loading third party libraries at *runtime*, and it does not seem like that is what you are after.